# How to make Bottom tab transparent @react-navigation/bottom-tabs V6

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-v6

I am using @react-navigation/bottom-tabs V6. I am trying to have transparent background on bottom. So far I cannot figure it out how to  do it. Any ideas?
Result so far:

[image]

Code so far:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
  
const theme = {
  colors: {
    background: "transparent",
  },
};

  <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      tabBarOptions={{
        style: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          borderTopWidth: 0,
          elevation: 0,
        }
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="HomeNavigation"
        component={HomeNavigation}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Home",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Icon />,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
```

How can I get rid off this background?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is the solution

first:

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
    tabBarStyle: {
      position: "absolute",
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      elevation: 0,
      borderTopWidth: 0,
    },
  }}
>
```

and  also this have to be added to the container:

```
const theme = {
  colors: {
    background: "transparent",
  },
};

<NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
   <BottomUserNavigation />
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately, it appears that I cannot click on any of the navbar buttons, but as mentioned, the background becomes transparent.

Answer (score 0):

The Tab.Navigator Not have props called tabBarOptions.

the tabBarOptions found in screenOptions.

You can do that ->

```
    <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: "transparent" },
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="HomeNavigation"
          component={HomeNavigation}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Home",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Icon />,
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Just add tabBarStyle props in the tabBarStyle and set the styles

Or you can add screen options for only one screen like that.

```
    <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="HomeNavigation"
          component={HomeNavigation}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Home",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Icon />,
            tabBarStyle:{backgroundColor:"transparent"}
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: No, still the same effect like on the screen above.